# Datatables page loading issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatable

I am using [datatables](https://datatables.net/) v1.10.11 and Jquery v 2.2.0

One of the features of datatables allows for the 'hiding' of columns using the following [columns.visible](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.visible) API option.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    //Hide the first column with columnDefs:
    $('#example').dataTable({
      "columnDefs": [{
        "visible": false,
        "targets": 0
      }]
    });
  }); 
  </script>
```

Again this does work, however on page load I can see the hidden columns for a split second (very briefly).

This only seems to be the case when using Google Chrome (Version 48.0.2564.103 m). Both IE (11) and FFox (41.0.1) are fine, the table loads as expected with no 'lag'.

Why would this happen? I thought it may have something to do with the ordering of my JS or CSS, the only dependency required for datatables is Jquery and I have this placed first.

See order of my JS and CSS below;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">

        <title>My Title</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.0/css/buttons.bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.0.0/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.1.0/css/select.bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css"/>
        <!-- Custom CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css"/>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.0/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.0/js/buttons.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.0/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.0/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.0.0/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.0.0/js/responsive.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.1.0/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/media/js/jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>

        <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
```

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this one. I've already tried to re-order and delete certain JS and CSS files however it doesn't seem to make any difference. Is there some sort of pre-loading issue with Chrome?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is your javascript code inside a $(document).ready() or another page load event?

Comment: Ok, looks like some sync problem between page load and and the component's features load.. You can mind to set some "default" CSS to your columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happening because dataTables runs after the document loads if you're in a $(document).ready({}); block.  So basically the columns are not hidden until the javascript adds the necessary CSS to hide them.  You can apply your own custom CSS to those cells if you don't want the delay in hiding them.

Just add a class to them and apply display:none to the class.

Or you could set the table to display:none, and then show it when dataTables is done initializing using the [initComplete](https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete) event. That way when it does show, the column will be hidden already.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //Hide the first column with columnDefs:
        $('#example').dataTable({
            "columnDefs": [{
                "visible": false,
                "targets": 0
            }],
            "initComplete": function() {
                $(this).show();
            }
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

Provided a full jsFiddle, working example here...

https://jsfiddle.net/rsmcyz4q/

Complete example below...

**HTML**

```
<table id="example">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>COLUMN 1</th>
    <th>COLUMN 2</th>
    <th>COLUMN 3</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>ROW 1</td>
    <td>ROW 1</td>
    <td>ROW 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ROW 2</td>
    <td>ROW 2</td>
    <td>ROW 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ROW 3</td>
    <td>ROW 3</td>
    <td>ROW 3</td>
  </tr>  
</tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
#example { display: none; }
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    //Hide the first column with columnDefs:
    $('#example').dataTable({
      "columnDefs": [{
        "visible": false,
        "targets": 0
      }],
      "initComplete": function() {
        $(this).show();
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: @johnny_s, not sure why it's only happening in chrome.  You could set the table to display:none, and then show it when dataTAbles is done initializing using the "initComplete" event.  That way when it does show, the column will be hidden already.

Comment: @johnny_s I updated the example to show the initComplete.  If using $(this).show() does not work, try using $('#example').show();

Comment: Thanks for this @Phil however it's not working. Nothing happens. Whenever I replace `$(this).show();` with `alert( 'DataTables has finished its initialisation.' );` I do see the alert. Any ideas? I've also tried `$('#example').show()`.

Comment: @johnny_s Not sure without seeing the updated code.  You could always wrap the table in a div with display:none, and then in the initComplete call show() on that div, which would in turn show the table.